# What free or cheap (<$200/month) API would you suggest to get stock options data?

Tags: options, programming

Here is what I am looking for:

1. I would like to cover the greatest possible percentage of all existing options worldwide (with US options being the top priority though).
2. I would prefer live data but end of day could be sufficient.
3. It needs to be somewhat cheap. A few hundred dollars per month at most for my use case:
4. I would like create an options screener. So would ideally update all option prices live, but could be hourly or once a day at least, depending on pricing as mentioned in 3).

Tech Stack: Firestore for the DB, Node.js backend, vanilla JS front-end.

Comment: IEX gets you end of day US options data. https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#end-of-day-options. Their cheapest subscription offers you approx 5000 calls to option prices (I _think_ single point level) per month and costs about 110 USD/annual. You could test their API and extrapolate the necessary subscription plan‘s cost. Their EOD options data is not made public before 9:30 am NY time of the following day if I remember correctly.

Comment: Quandl has US options implied volatilities, but you have to get in touch with them re pricing I think: https://www.quandl.com/data/VOL

Comment: NB: Quandl offers multiple option data sets from different providers.